# Возникновение ошибок в другом домене приложения c#

Tags: c#, cross-domain

Если загрузить сборку приложения в отдельный домен, то в случае появления не обрабатываемых исключений "Stack overflow exception", повреждения памяти, будет ли главный домен приложения работать, или он положит весь процесс?

Comment: Стек принадлежит Thread-y, попробуйте выполнять такие действия в отдельном Thread. Креш второстепенных Thread в с++ не влияет на работу основного. Не уверен так ли в с#, вероятнее всего да. Продолжить работу Thread нельзя, но можно понять на какой фазе он лёг.

Comment: @nick_n_a, т.е если если нужно сделать кроссдоменное приложение и что бы если домен падал, приложение не умерало, то нужно это кросс доменное взаимодействие в отдельном потоке делать?

Comment: @nick_n_a не, не работает.

Comment: @iluxa1810 вижу... удивился. Ну... второй вариант - сделать прослойку на с++, и в с++ try-catch добавить... (что б native лечить)

Comment: @nick_n_a, а есть какая-то CER. Никогда с ним не работал, но там можно атрибутам помечать методы, которые поверждают процесс. Это каким-нибудь можно использовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Starting with the .NET Framework version 2.0, a StackOverflowException
>   object cannot be caught by a try-catch block and the corresponding
>   process is terminated by default. Consequently, users are advised to
>   write their code to detect and prevent a stack overflow. For example,
>   if your application depends on recursion, use a counter or a state
>   condition to terminate the recursive loop. Note that an application
>   that hosts the common language runtime (CLR) can specify that the CLR
>   unload the application domain where the stack overflow exception
>   occurs and let the corresponding process continue. For more
>   information, see ICLRPolicyManager Interface and Hosting the Common
>   Language Runtime.

Начиная с версии 2,0 переполнение стека можно перехватить только если оно брошено пользователем.

Получается, что если верить вот [этому](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987215/handling-critical-exceptions-in-different-appdomains) ответу, то даже переполнение в другом домене убивает процесс, аргументируя это тем, что возможно все место в стеке закончилось и ничего сделать не получится.

Есть еще вот такая статья на [хабре](https://habr.com/company/jugru/blog/426045/), где проделываются хаки через WinApi, которые позволяют не умереть процессу, но это рисковое дело...

Статья рекомендует так же использовать `RuntimeHelpers`, например есть такой метод 
[RuntimeHelpers.ProbeForSufficientStack](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.runtimehelpers.probeforsufficientstack?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Runtime_CompilerServices_RuntimeHelpers_ProbeForSufficientStack), который проверяет возможность выделения памяти.

Еще в 7,2 появились `Span` и `stackallock/trystackalloc`, которые позволяют безопасно размещать данные в стеке:

```
Span<byte> span;
if (CanAllocateOnStack(size))
         span = stackalloc byte[size];
else
         span = new byte[size];
```

**UPD**

По поводу варианта с отдельным потоком:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var thread=new Thread(() => { Recursive(); });
    try
    {
        thread.Start();
        while (thread.IsAlive)
        {
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        throw;
    }

}


static void Recursive()
{
    Recursive();
}
```

Процесс все равно погибает целиком.

Вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/907230/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81) мой вопрос на эту тему.

**UPD2**

Как вариант, можно использовать `StackTrace().FrameCount`, но если у нас нету доступа к исходникам, то воткнуть его в рекурсию мы не сможем, что бы проверять время от времени и вываливаться на пороге переполнения стека.

Comment: Проблема со взаимодействием с библиотеками на native c++ которые могут время от времени разрушать память. Исходного кода к сожалению нет поэтому скорее всего придется загружать сборки в отдельные процессы

Comment: Так вопрос был пор домен, а не про поток.